# Android: HTML encoder

Tags: java, android, html-encode

I have html text that I want to show in webview.

As [specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), data must be URI-escaped.
So I tried to use URLEncoder.encode() function, but that will not help me, as it converts blank space with plus sign.

So is there any encoding function available?

Comment: What's the problem with encoding spaces as `+`?  That *is* correct escaping...

Comment: That will not decoded by Webview and it will show + instead of blank space like &nbsp;

Comment: How about manual replacement of the characters mentioned in the specification ?

Comment: Why the question is down voted? anyway I came up with solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Seb said, I created my own function that worked for me:

```
public String encodeHTML(String s)
{
    s = s.replaceAll("#", "%23");
    s = s.replaceAll("%", "%25");
    return s;
}
```

Any improvement in this approach will be appreciated.

Comment: I posted an improvement, just above. Please change to selected answer :)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a few months old, but [TextUtils.htmlEncode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode%28java.lang.String%29) is a great little method that does exactly just that.

Answer (score 0):

try to use either  `Html.fromhtml(string)` or `StringEscapeutil utility(download this jar)` after downloading it,lets try something like below

`StringEscapeUtils strutil  =  new StringEscapeUtils();
title =    strutil.escapeHtml(title);`

...I think it may help you..

Comment: try to use StringEscape utility,it effects the same,what you need.

Comment: I tried that also, but that converts all the characters, so tag will be appear in WebView. As specification I need to convert only some of the characters, look at my own answer that worked for me..